# Querying and mapping using Vapor

Tags: swift, vapor

I'm trying to write a function using Swift and Vapor but I don't understand why one statement gets printed before the other:

```
// Logout user
func logout(_ req: Request) throws -> Future<APIResponseMessage> {
    let userID = self.checkAccessToken(req: req)

    // Delete access token here

    let apiResponseMessage = APIResponseMessage()
    apiResponseMessage.message = "success"
    apiResponseMessage.userID = userID
    return apiResponseMessage.create(on: req)
}

func checkAccessToken(req: Request) -> Int {
    let bearerAuthorization = req.http.headers.bearerAuthorization
    guard let _bearerAuthorization = bearerAuthorization else {
        // Works fine
        print("no bearer incluced")
        return 0
    }

    let _ = AccessToken.query(on: req).filter(\.accessToken == _bearerAuthorization.token).first().map(to: Int.self) { queriedAccessToken in
        // This should be first
        print("This gets printed second")
        return queriedAccessToken!.userID!
    }

    // This should be second
    print("This gets printed first")
    return 0
}
```

Can anyone tell me how to make the second print statement wait until the first one is completed?

Right now it's causing my logout function to run with `userID == 0` when this shouldn't be the case

Comment: what is the return type of `map(to: Int.self)` ?

Comment: `EventLoopFuture<Int>`

Comment: It's due to the fact that the code is async. Vapor 3 uses Futures and since Swift doesn't provide async/await yet, you'll need to use one of the methods provided by Vapor to "wait" for the previous future: have a look at https://docs.vapor.codes/3.0/async/overview/#chaining

Answer (score 3):

As @nathan said, this is due to your code being async. Your `.map` callback is like the closure you pass into to a `URLSession.dataTask` when making request's to an external API for an iOS app.

Vapor uses a slightly different async model then what you use in iOS though, using promises and futures instead of callback closures. You can read about them [in the docs](https://docs.vapor.codes/3.0/async/overview/).

In your case, you want to return the `userID` you get from the `AccessToken` query. To do this, you first need to change your method's return type from `Int` to `Future<Int>`. Then, instead of assigning the result of the `.map` call to `_`, you can return it from the method:

```
func checkAccessToken(req: Request) -> Future<Int> {
    let bearerAuthorization = req.http.headers.bearerAuthorization
    guard let _bearerAuthorization = bearerAuthorization else {
        return req.future(0)
    }

    return AccessToken.query(on: req).filter(\.accessToken == _bearerAuthorization.token).first().map(to: Int.self) { queriedAccessToken in
        return queriedAccessToken!.userID!
    }
}
```

I would suggest you look into error handling for your `queriedAccessToken` and `userID` values so you aren't force-unwrapping them.